# AWT Graphics not Translating Correctly

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, graphics2d

I'm making a simple 2-D game for which I'd like to move the camera with the mouse. There are loads of better ways to do this, I'm sure, but I decided to try out the Graphics2D method `setTransform()`.

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.translate(mousex, 0);

Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
g2d.setTransform(at);
```

However, the graphics don't translate linearly with the mouse, as you can see from the images below. For the first few pixels it seems to move correctly, but it kind of *slows down later*?

By the way, the mouse is indicated by the blue circle.

[image]

[image]

When the mouse is near the edge of the frame, the graphics moves almost linearly with it to the right.
When the mouse is dragged further to the right, the graphics moves with it, but with a kind of lag (it shouldn't)

The white border around the blocks represents the outline of the graphics that should be moving.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Bruh extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener
{
    int mousex = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        f.setUndecorated(true);
        
        f.add(new Bruh());
        
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    Bruh()
    {
        setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.translate(mousex, 0);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.setTransform(at);

        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 100, 100, 100);

        g2d.dispose();

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(mousex-5, 200-5, 10, 10);

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        mousex = e.getX();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mousex = e.getX();
    }
}
```

## TL;DR

The `setTransform(AffineTransform at)` function of Graphics2D isn't working as intended. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Comment: @AndrewThompson You're absolutely right, this was just the quickest way I could frame the question. I'll be updating the question ASAP

Comment: @user85421 I did that in my original program, but must have forgot to add it here. Thanks!

Comment: posted code works fine for me - the blue dot is always on the bottom left corner of the white square and perfectly following mouse as expected (horizontal position only)

Comment: Ditto what @user85421 just said.

Comment: Huh. I'm using a laptop, is there any way that that could make a difference? I'm just spitballing here, because the discrepancy is quite clear for me.

Comment: So I've tested it myself, and the issue seems to arise either from using a touchpad, or the pixel density of my laptop (I'm absolutely no expert here). Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: *"Is there any way to fix this?"* I hope so, but am unable to contribute anything of value. I don't use laptops & am unfamiliar with the intricacies thereof. All the best with it. If you've not got a solution within 2 days, tag me and I might add a bounty. Oh, one thing, check you've got the latest drivers for the video card. I ***doubt*** that's the problem, but doing so has managed to fix some other visual problems.

Comment: Will do. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I got the answer. The problem isn't in my code, or with my touchpad scrolling.

On my laptop, I had set the scaling of the display to 125%, causing everything to work normally EXCEPT apps that use default scaling - Java being one of them.

The problem was that my mouse moved correctly (because that's what mice do) but the in-built graphics of java were responding to the default scaling of the display i.e. 125%. So everything was moving 1.25 times slower than expected.